# How to create custom error classes in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

What is the right way to create custom error classes in Ember and where to put the error class definition files in Ember CLI?

All code samples that I have found are messing around with JavaScript object prototypes. Why can't I just call Ember.Error.extend like we do for normal Ember objects?

Proper place for custom error classes should be under app/errors/ directory, but it seems that Ember CLI is not resolving those files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create custom file for example in `app/errors/` directory, and call it `custom-error.js`.

Use following code as base to declare your custom error class:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

let CustomError = function (errors, message = 'This error is result of my custom logic.') {
  Ember.Error.call(this, message);

  this.errors = errors || [
    {
      title: 'This is custom error.',
      detail: message
    }
  ];
}

CustomError.prototype = Object.create(Ember.Error.prototype);

export default CustomError;
```

Then if you want to use this error somewhere:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import CustomError from '../errors/custom-error';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
  testCustomError: Ember.on('init', () => {
    let customErrorInstance = new CustomError();
    console.log(customErrorInstance);
  })
});
```

Result of `console.log(customErrorInstance)` is:

> CustomError {description: undefined, fileName: undefined, lineNumber:
>   undefined, message: "This error is result of my custom logic.", name:
>   "Error"…}

- [Working demo.](http://ember-twiddle.com/be2a0c17d4c236d81843)
- [Full code behind demo.](https://gist.github.com/Kuzirashi/be2a0c17d4c236d81843)

Comment: Thanks for quick and detailed answer. Got my code working nicely.